# Automatically changing the width of box when resizing the browser window?

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 boxes. #content-left and #content-right gets automatically resized in height when the window resizes. What I'm trying to is to automatically resize the #content-right in width too to fill in the gap between these 2 boxes.

The code I wrote so far works only on first page load or on refresh. It doesn't work when the window gets resized. What am I doing wrong?

[Live version.](http://jsfiddle.net/fcQuZ/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $(window).load(function() {
    scrollPaneLoad();
  });

  function scrollPaneLoad() {
      if ($(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
        main_height = $(document).height();
      } else {
        main_height = $(window).height();
      }
      div_height = main_height - $('#header-outer').height() - $('#footer').height();
      if (div_height < 400) div_height = 400;
      $('#content-right, #content-left').css({height: div_height + 'px'});
      img_width = $('img.content-left-img').width();
      content_right_width = 945 - img_width;
      $('#content-left').css({width: img_width + 'px'});
      $('#content-right').css({width: content_right_width + 'px'});
      $('#content-right').jScrollPane(
        {
          showArrows: true,
          horizontalGutter: 10
        }
      );
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    scrollPaneLoad();       
  });  

});
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-left">
    <img src="img/home.jpg" class="content-left-img" />
  </div><!--eof #content-left-->
  <div id="content-right">
    <div class="inner">
      <!--content goes here-->
    </div><!--eof .inner-->
  </div><!--eof #content-right-->
  <div class="float-fix"></div>
</div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```css
#content {
    width:950px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#content-left {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:565px;
    min-height:400px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -khtml-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#content-left img.content-left-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#content-right {
    float:right;
    width:380px;
}
#content-right .inner {
    padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: Use css `position: static` better than JavaScript

Comment: **Reference:**  ***The code I wrote so far works only on first page load or on refresh.***  I notice that when the browser window is of short height, the page "looks" normal `onload`. However when accessing your test site with browser at maximum viewport size it has a squashed text panel. Just a heads up if you didn't know.

Comment: [**Live Site in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fcQuZ/). Note: No corrections have been done and URL's are now absolute.

Comment: I think Alvin Wong meant `position: fixed`.

Comment: @Afmrak Yesssss... you're right

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting the widths to constant values, hence they won't change even if you resize the window. Change the heights and widths to percentage values, like 60%, or 70%, and they will expand or contract with the window. Mind you, if the element contracts, its contents may spill out in an ugly manner.

Comment: I know that but why does it work when I refresh the page but not when I resize it?